# Reputation glitch?

Tags: bug, reputation

I see here that I have earned 77 reputation today:

[image]

but here I see I earned only 69 reputation:

[image]

And in reputation page also I see 69:

[image]

So, is this a glitch?

Comment: [Caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) ...

Comment: what is that @rene?

Comment: Does that mean it is a glitch with the site?

Comment: no @RobertLongson. It's still 69 for me

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414

Comment: I am using the same site as u are @RobertLongson

Comment: ok @rene. So, I actually have earned 77 reputation today

Comment: Numbers like the reputation of users, the number of views on a post etc aren't mission-critical and so they don't need to be 100% exact all the time... so these values are updated after a certain amount of time... till that time has passed the old value is retained... this is called caching... if the values were loaded in real-time then that would put a lot of load on the servers... (at least that is how I understand it)

Comment: ok. @RobertLongson. Let me try to clear the cache and those things and try

Comment: I get it @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine

Comment: It could also be due to the deletion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615621/why-is-firebase-not-connecting). The achievement inbox isn't really great at dealing with certain types of reputation loss, particularly related to deletion. All of that is by design, however

Comment: @Sambhav.K note that some caching was done on the server-side, so clearing the browser's (client-side) cache still won't suddenly update it.

Comment: Just note that we are **not** talking about client-side cache. Most of the caching effects you see here are server-side and is not something you or we can clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classical example of [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414) issue.

Though it shows you have earned 77 reputation today

[image: 77today]

As `@Zoe` pointed out in their [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417151/reputation-glitch#comment903230_417151), the deduction of net 8 points [10(upvote) - 2(downvote) = 8] arising from the [question deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615621/why-is-firebase-not-connecting) is yet to be adjusted.

[image: -8deletion]